# NetBeans Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException Java3D 1.5.2

Tags: java, arrays, exception, java-3d

EDIT: NEW CODE AND OUTPUT AFTER DASHED LINE

This is for a school assignment but I just can't find anything that will rid me of this problem. What the program is suppose to do is take a GeneralPath object and create a Shape3D object with it using a class called RotatedShape. It has a constructor (the only one needed for the project) that takes the GeneralPath as a parameter. With this, the path is meant to be rotated around an axis to display a solid shape, similar to a Torus. The code is based off of code from the textbook I'm using, as most projects in the class usually are.

The exception happens here: qa.setCoordinates(i * m, ptsList); which is in the RotatedShape class, near the bottom. I know the problem is coming from using ptsList as a parameter because earlier I was having the same problem with that Point3d array when initializing it, hence why its size is currently set to 100 as a placeholder.

When run, the GUI displays nothing and I get this in my console output window:

```
x = 0.1 y = -0.5
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.media.j3d.GeometryArrayRetained.setCoordinates(GeometryArrayRetained.java:3849)
    at javax.media.j3d.GeometryArrayRetained.setCoordinates(GeometryArrayRetained.java:3849)
    at javax.media.j3d.GeometryArray.setCoordinates(GeometryArray.java:1469)
    at RotatedShape.<init>(Project8.java:202)
    at Project8.createSceneGraph(Project8.java:58)
    at Project8.init(Project8.java:27)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame.run(MainFrame.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 8 seconds)
```

I can clearly see where the error is occurring and I have an idea as to what the problem is, but I have no idea how to go about fixing it. It's probably something stupid about initializing the array or something, but I can't seem to find anything that helps.

Below is the code that is all in one file, as the professor wants it.

```
import javax.vecmath.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import java.applet.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Project8 extends Applet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame(new Project8(), 640, 480);
    }

    public void init() {
        // create canvas
        GraphicsConfiguration gc
                = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D cv = new Canvas3D(gc);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        BranchGroup bg = createSceneGraph();
        bg.compile();
        SimpleUniverse su = new SimpleUniverse(cv);
        su.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        su.addBranchGraph(bg);
    }

    private BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
        BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
        TransformGroup spin = new TransformGroup();
        spin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        root.addChild(spin);

        Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
        tr.setScale(0.8);
        tr.setRotation(new AxisAngle4d(1, 0, 0, Math.PI / 6));
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(tr);
        spin.addChild(tg);

        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
        path.moveTo(0.1f, -0.5f);
        path.quadTo(0.5f, 1, 0.8f, 0.5f);
        path.lineTo(1, 0.2f);
        path.closePath();
        Shape3D shape = new RotatedShape(path);
        Appearance ap = new Appearance();
        ap.setMaterial(new Material());
        shape.setAppearance(ap);
        tg.addChild(shape);

        Alpha alpha = new Alpha(-1, 8000);
        RotationInterpolator rotator = new RotationInterpolator(alpha, spin);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere();
        rotator.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
        spin.addChild(rotator);

        // background and lights
        Background background = new Background(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        background.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(background);
        AmbientLight light = new AmbientLight(true, new Color3f(Color.blue));
        light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(light);
        PointLight ptlight = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.white),
                new Point3f(3f, 3f, 3f), new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
        ptlight.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(ptlight);
        return root;
    }
}

class RotatedShape extends Shape3D {

    public RotatedShape(GeneralPath path) {
        int depth = 100;
        PathIterator iter = path.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform());
        Point3d[] ptsList = new Point3d[depth];
        float[] seg = new float[6];
        float x = 0, y = 0;
        float x0 = 0, y0 = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        while (!iter.isDone()) {
            int segType = iter.currentSegment(seg);
            switch (segType) {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    x = x0 = seg[0];
                    y = y0 = seg[1];
                    System.out.println("x = " + x + " y = " + y);
                    ptsList[pos] = new Point3d(x, y, 0);
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    x = seg[0];
                    y = seg[1];
                    ptsList[pos] = new Point3d(x, y, 0);
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                        float t = (float) i / 10f;
                        float xi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * x + 2 * t * (1 - t) * seg[0] + t * t * seg[2];
                        float yi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * y + 2 * t * (1 - t) * seg[1] + t * t * seg[3];
                        ptsList[pos] = new Point3d(xi, yi, 0);
                        pos++;
                    }
                    x = seg[2];
                    y = seg[3];
                    ptsList[pos] = new Point3d(x, y, 0);
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                        float t = (float) i / 20f;

                        float xi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * x + 3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * seg[0]
                            + 3 * t * t * (1 - t) * seg[2] + t * t * t * seg[4];
                        float yi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * y + 3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * seg[1]
                            + 3 * t * t * (1 - t) * seg[3] + t * t * t * seg[5];
                        ptsList[pos] = new Point3d(xi, yi, 0);
                        pos++;
                    }
                    x = seg[2];
                    y = seg[3];
                    ptsList[pos] = new Point3d(x, y, 0);
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                    x = x0;
                    y = y0;
                    ptsList[pos] = new Point3d(x, y, 0);
                    pos++;
                    break;
            }
            iter.next();
        }

        int m = 20;
        //int n = 40;
        int n = ptsList.length;

        Transform3D rot2 = new Transform3D();
        rot2.rotY(2.0 * Math.PI / n);
        IndexedQuadArray qa = new IndexedQuadArray(m * n,
                IndexedQuadArray.COORDINATES, 4 * m * n);
        int quadIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            qa.setCoordinates(i * m, ptsList);
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                rot2.transform(ptsList[j]);
                int[] quadCoords = {i * m + j, ((i + 1) % n) * m + j,
                    ((i + 1) % n) * m + ((j + 1) % m), i * m + ((j + 1) % m)};
                qa.setCoordinateIndices(quadIndex, quadCoords);
                quadIndex += 4;
            }
        }
        GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(qa);
        NormalGenerator ng = new NormalGenerator();
        ng.generateNormals(gi);
        this.setGeometry(gi.getGeometryArray());
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.vecmath.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import java.applet.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.geom.GeneralPath;
import java.awt.geom.PathIterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Project8 extends Applet {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MainFrame(new Project8(), 640, 480);
    }

    public void init() {
        // create canvas
        GraphicsConfiguration gc
                = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D cv = new Canvas3D(gc);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        BranchGroup bg = createSceneGraph();
        bg.compile();
        SimpleUniverse su = new SimpleUniverse(cv);
        su.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        su.addBranchGraph(bg);
    }

    private BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
        BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
        TransformGroup spin = new TransformGroup();
        spin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        root.addChild(spin);

        Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
        tr.setScale(0.8);
        tr.setRotation(new AxisAngle4d(1, 0, 0, Math.PI / 6));
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(tr);
        spin.addChild(tg);

        GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
        path.moveTo(0.1f, -0.5f);
        path.quadTo(0.5f, 1, 0.8f, 0.5f);
        path.lineTo(1, 0.2f);
        path.closePath();
        Shape3D shape = new RotatedShape(path);
        Appearance ap = new Appearance();
        ap.setMaterial(new Material());
        shape.setAppearance(ap);
        tg.addChild(shape);

        Alpha alpha = new Alpha(-1, 8000);
        RotationInterpolator rotator = new RotationInterpolator(alpha, spin);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere();
        rotator.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
        spin.addChild(rotator);

        // background and lights
        Background background = new Background(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        background.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(background);
        AmbientLight light = new AmbientLight(true, new Color3f(Color.blue));
        light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(light);
        PointLight ptlight = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.white),
                new Point3f(3f, 3f, 3f), new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
        ptlight.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(ptlight);
        return root;
    }
}

class RotatedShape extends Shape3D {

    public RotatedShape(GeneralPath path) {
        int depth = 100;
        PathIterator iter = path.getPathIterator(new AffineTransform());
        Vector ptsVector = new Vector();
        float[] seg = new float[6];
        float x = 0, y = 0;
        float x0 = 0, y0 = 0;
        int pos = 0;
        while (!iter.isDone()) {
            int segType = iter.currentSegment(seg);
            switch (segType) {
                case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
                    x = x0 = seg[0];
                    y = y0 = seg[1];
                    ptsVector.add(new Point3d(x, y, 0));
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
                    x = seg[0];
                    y = seg[1];
                    ptsVector.add(new Point3d(x, y, 0));
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
                    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
                        float t = (float) i / 10f;
                        float xi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * x + 2 * t * (1 - t) * seg[0] + t * t * seg[2];
                        float yi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * y + 2 * t * (1 - t) * seg[1] + t * t * seg[3];
                        ptsVector.add(new Point3d(xi, yi, 0));
                        pos++;
                    }
                    x = seg[2];
                    y = seg[3];
                    ptsVector.add(new Point3d(x, y, 0));
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
                    for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++) {
                        float t = (float) i / 20f;

                        float xi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * x + 3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * seg[0]
                            + 3 * t * t * (1 - t) * seg[2] + t * t * t * seg[4];
                        float yi = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * y + 3 * t * (1 - t) * (1 - t) * seg[1]
                            + 3 * t * t * (1 - t) * seg[3] + t * t * t * seg[5];
                        ptsVector.add(new Point3d(xi, yi, 0));
                        pos++;
                    }
                    x = seg[2];
                    y = seg[3];
                    ptsVector.add(new Point3d(x, y, 0));
                    pos++;
                    break;
                case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
                    x = x0;
                    y = y0;
                    ptsVector.add(new Point3d(x, y, 0));
                    pos++;
                    break;
            }
            iter.next();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < ptsVector.size(); i++)
            System.out.println("Vector = " + ptsVector.elementAt(i) + " at " + i);
        System.out.println("pos = " + pos);

        Point3d[] ptsArray = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < ptsVector.size(); i++) {
            ptsArray[i] = (Point3d) ptsVector.elementAt(i);
        }
       // Point3d[] ptsArray = ptsVector.toArray(new Point3d(ptsVector.size()));
        int m = 20;
        //int n = 40;
        int n = ptsArray.length;

        Transform3D rot2 = new Transform3D();
        rot2.rotY(2.0 * Math.PI / n);
        IndexedQuadArray qa = new IndexedQuadArray(m * n,
                IndexedQuadArray.COORDINATES, 4 * m * n);
        int quadIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("i = " + i);
            qa.setCoordinates(i * m, ptsArray);
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                rot2.transform(ptsArray[j]);
                int[] quadCoords = {i * m + j, ((i + 1) % n) * m + j,
                    ((i + 1) % n) * m + ((j + 1) % m), i * m + ((j + 1) % m)};
                qa.setCoordinateIndices(quadIndex, quadCoords);
                quadIndex += 4;
            }
        }
        GeometryInfo gi = new GeometryInfo(qa);
        NormalGenerator ng = new NormalGenerator();
        ng.generateNormals(gi);
        this.setGeometry(gi.getGeometryArray());
    }
}
```

Output:

```
run:
Vector = (0.10000000149011612, -0.5, 0.0) at 0
Vector = (0.17899999022483826, -0.2199999839067459, 0.0) at 1
Vector = (0.25600001215934753, 0.020000001415610313, 0.0) at 2
Vector = (0.3310000002384186, 0.2200000286102295, 0.0) at 3
Vector = (0.40400004386901855, 0.3800000250339508, 0.0) at 4
Vector = (0.4750000238418579, 0.5, 0.0) at 5
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NullPointerException
Vector = (0.5440000295639038, 0.5800000429153442, 0.0) at 6
    at RotatedShape.<init>(Project8.java:197)
Vector = (0.6110000014305115, 0.6200000047683716, 0.0) at 7
Vector = (0.6759999990463257, 0.6200000047683716, 0.0) at 8
Vector = (0.7389999628067017, 0.5800000429153442, 0.0) at 9
Vector = (0.800000011920929, 0.5, 0.0) at 10
Vector = (1.0, 0.20000000298023224, 0.0) at 11
Vector = (0.10000000149011612, -0.5, 0.0) at 12
pos = 13
    at Project8.createSceneGraph(Project8.java:58)
    at Project8.init(Project8.java:27)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame.run(MainFrame.java:267)
    at com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame.run(MainFrame.java:267)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Ensure that ptsList doesn't contain any null references, look at all indices from 0 to length - 1. Do you use Java3D 1.6.0?

Comment: Maybe I'm just being really dumb about arrays but how do I initialize an empty array without adding anything to it at the start? So far I just do Point3d[] array; I guess I'll try looking at the inputs a bit more first to make sure they're okay. I am using Java3D 1.5.2; I'll go put that in the main question.

Comment: BranchGroup bg = createSceneGraph(); I think your error pass this line. where you create object to call  this method ?

Comment: can you post 'new MainFrame()' call code ?

Comment: I didn't write MainFrame, it's built into Java3D. It's definitely not that line; I've used it in all my other projects and they've never given me this error. It has to be coming from the array since that's where the exception stuff points to when I run the code.

Comment: I'm sorry to insist but please switch to Java3D 1.6.0 even though it is for an assignment. The source code of Java3D 1.5.2 might become unavailable in the future and anyway, Java3D 1.5.2 is no longer maintained, using it is very risky, you can waste a lot of time with its unfixed bugs. Moreover, if you want to get some help, I need to know exactly what happens in Java3D when you pass your coordinates to it... which is easier with Java3D 1.6.0 source code available on Github and on the JogAmp GIT repository.

Comment: Simply loop on all indices and check whether null is stored. Point3d[] ptsList = new Point3d[depth]; creates the array but at this time, pstList[0] is null. Filling the array with a dummy point is a bad idea. Building a smaller array without null has a chance to work but it would be better to know why there are some null references.

Comment: Print pos after the loop. If it is strictly less than length - 1, copy your array into a small one, its size will be equal to pos + 1.

Comment: Okay so I edited my code a bit to include a Vector which helped me store the points better but it hasn't helped much. I just edited my code in the post to reflect the changes I made, as well as include the print statements you told me to include for checking. Honestly, it seems like they're being stored fine and everything, it's just saving them into a new array that's screwing with them. I also added the output of the vectors that you told me to do you so can see for yourself.

Comment: Also I will change to 1.6 later tonight if I can't get this working by then.

Comment: You have to write: Point3d[] ptsArray = new Point3d[ptsVector.size()]; You really need to learn the basics of Java arrays.